# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation but nothing happens

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

our app got rejected, becouse the app does not rotate in upside down orientation.

so we have an tabbar App, adding this code to all tabs...

shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

makes no sense, add this code to a Appdelegate doesn't helps, what we do wrong?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITabbarcontroller is a subclass of UIViewcontroller. To solve you problem just subclass or add a category for you UITabbarcontroller implementing:

```
@interface UITabBarController (rotation)
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
@end

@implementation UITabBarController (rotation)
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
     return YES;
}
@end
```

If you want to make the tabbar only rotate to portrait and upside down just use th following code instead

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Comment: can you please explain what i should do, i am a newbe in iOS

Comment: yeah, first of all read about categories here: http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html

Comment: And i edited my answer so you can see the category you should use. please tell me if it works good luck

Comment: thats looks good, in Simulator, how can i block the landscape rotation? I need only the upsidedown.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that **each** `UIViewController` implements

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: but if i have it on the first tab, at least the first tab must rotate... or not?

Comment: Not. A `UITabBarController` will only autorotate if all of its view controllers are set to autorotate.

Comment: well, i have done this, but still the same... i have found this one "I remember encountering this once.  I think the problem turned out to 
be that my TabBarController's view wasn't a direct subview of the 
window, but was enclosed in some other view instead.  After placing 
the view as a direct child of the window, it worked. " maybe you can explain me, what he mean, or how to do it :)